# Remove Post `<a>` Wrap in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with the way Wordpress creates code.

My posts should be wrapped inside a div but Wordpress creates a few extra `<a>` wraps and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Does anyone has an idea?

My code below.

```
<article @php(post_class(mainpagepost))>
  <div class="entry-center">
    <header class="entry-header">
      <div class="entry-header-subinfo">
        @php(the_category()) | @php(the_date())
      </div>
      <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ get_permalink() }}">{{ get_the_title() }}</a></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-summary">
      @php(the_excerpt())
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="{{ get_permalink() }}">READ MORE</button>
  </div>
    @php(the_post_thumbnail(entry-image))
</article>
```

It adds these lines of code over them.

```
  </a></div><a href="//localhost:3000/Git/VoiceBooking%20Blog/wordpress/index.php/2017/12/13/welcome-to-this-blog/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part in the code represents a link to the complete post:

```
<a href="{{ get_permalink() }}">
```

(plus the closing `</a>` tag for each of these.)

So if you remove those, you can get rid of those links. However, be aware that they lead to the full post - the code you posted above only will display part of the port (the excerpt), so you need some way to get users to see the full post. The way it's done in the code in your question is really quite common and is what people are used to.

ADDITION: Actually there is a closing `</a>` tag *missing* in your code, on this line:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="{{ get_permalink() }}">READ MORE</button>
```

That should be

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="{{ get_permalink() }}">READ MORE</a></button>
```

That probably causes some trouble in the HTML output when Wordpress or the browser tries to correct that incomplete link...